# Can't start the Python interpreter in PowerShell or Console anymore using "python", need to type "py"

Tags: python, powershell, path

I have a bit of a oddity going on I can't figure out why it's happening. I've installed the latest version of Python for Windows (3.8.5 64-bit), after removing the previous version, and the version which comes with Visual Studio as part of the Python development package in that IDE. Python installed fine, and also added the Environment variables which I activated in the installer. Now I opened the PowerShell to start the Python interpreter as I've done so often before, typed in python, and Windows 10 opened up the Windows store to suggest to install Python from the store... so, I made sure another time that Python installed the environment variables which it did.

I uninstalled and re-installed Python several times then, also rebooting the computer a few times inbetween, to make sure it could read the changed environment variables. No luck. After browsing the net for some times, I came across a post here which suggested to start the interpreter via the "py" command. Et voilá, it works...

Did they change something in one of the latest versions of Python in regards of the command to start the interpreter? I frankly have no idea what is going on here... starting it via "python" ALWAYS worked, with every former version of Python.

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor/1461471#1461471

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the problem for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you uninstall your previous version of Python, but in your environment variables, are you sure you just have 1 link to python.exe ? Maybe you've got an other path that doesn't work and your command can't execute well.

Comment: Yes, only the python38 location is linked in the environment variables (for my user, I didn't install Python for all users, as I only have 1 user anyway).